# Compare two sets in MySQL for equality

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to compare two sets for equality.

I have an **Employee** table as

```
emp_id  | Name    
-----------------
1         Thomas 
2         John
3         Jeff     
.....
.....
```

and an **Employee_Language** table

```
Emp_id | Language   
------------------
1        English
1        French
2        Thai         
3        English
3        French
3        Chinese 
...
...
```

So I need to find all employees who knows a list of given languages 
for example 'English,French'

I know, using

```
select * from employee_language lng 
 where find_in_set(lng.language,'English,French')
```

Will give a list of employees who either knows English or French .. How can I get employees who knows both ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
WHERE language IN('x','y') GROUP BY emp_id HAVING COUNT (*) = 2
```

(where '2' is the number of items in the IN clause)

So your whole query could be:

```
SELECT e.emp_Id
     , e.Name
  FROM Employee e
  JOIN Employee_Language l
    ON e.emp_id = l.emp_id
 WHERE l.Language IN('English', 'French')
 GROUP  
    BY e.emp_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00d74/3)

Comment: +1 for a simple logic. I have added the whole query if you don't mind.

Comment: @hims056 Why would he mind ? I upvoted for this whole query + fiddle ;)

Comment: See also this similar question/answer for a few more ways of doing this: [How do I select items from a table where a single column must contain two (or more) values?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45512/how-do-i-select-items-from-a-table-where-a-single-column-must-contain-two-or-mo/45516#45516)

Comment: Wondering why I couldn't remember answering this - July 2013!!

Answer (score 3):

I just Improved the Accepted Answer by removing the constant (2) in the 'HAVING' clause  and parameterized the criteria .. hope this help someone

```
set @lst = 'English,French,Chinese' ;

SELECT e.emp_Id,Name
 FROM Employee e
 JOIN Employee_Language l
 ON e.emp_id = l.emp_id
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(l.Language,@lst)
 GROUP BY e.emp_id 
 HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT LENGTH(@lst) - LENGTH(REPLACE(@lst, ',', '')) AS `occurrences`)+1 ;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39421/1)

Comment: Parametrizing may be good and wanted but why did you replace the `IN` condition with the `FIND_IN_SET()` ?

Comment: @ypercube I am afraid its not possible to parameterize a IN condition .

Answer (score 2):

The complete query:

```
select EMP.Name
from Employee EMP
where EMP.emp_id in 
(
   select EMP_L.emp_id
   FROM Employee_Language EMP_L
   EMP_L.emp_id
   WHERE Language in ('English','French')
   GROUP BY EMP_L.emp_id
   HAVING COUNT(*)=2
)
```

Comment: @Strawberry Because Everybody has the right to Answer the Question in their own Way. Welcome to SO.